# vertices cannot be scaled (skin modifier+subdiv. modifier) Blender 3.0.0

Tags: vertices, transforms

I'm currently trying to model a tree by setting single vertices, connecting them and then using the skin and subdiv modifiers.
This method comes from this video from Agustín Hönnun

Link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUyoDHYKt8Q&t=11s

Now the problem is that I cannot scale the individual vertices.
In the video you can see that this should work, but it doesn't.

Can someone tell me why this is?

I've tried reducing a cube to a vert and then expanding it AND I've set a single vert and expanded it, neither of which worked.

Changing the pivot point also didn't work.

Blender version is 3.0.0

Thank you for your Help

Comment: Vertices cannot be scaled. They are single mathematical points, and have no size. You’ve misunderstood something in the video.

Comment: It's called extrusion. select a vertex and press `E` to extrude it

Comment: @TheLabCat oh he probably is refering to skin resizing with `Ctrl+A` https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/skin_resize.html

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thanks, I needed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Skin Modifier, use <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd> to scale a vertex.

Joey Carlino has some good YT videos on modelling with the Skin Modifier. [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAAwy_l4jw4) is about character modelling, but shows all the techniques and shortcuts that you can use.

Comment: you can't scale a vertex. it's called [skin resizing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/skin_resize.html)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I will not enjoy this, I will not enjoy this, I will not enjoy this…

Comment: My terminology may be wrong but it does the job! :^)